# Confusion about PHP 7 refcount

Tags: php, php-internals

```
<?php

$s = "foobar";

$t = $s;

$u = $s;

echo PHP_VERSION . "\n";

debug_zval_dump($s);

xdebug_debug_zval('s');
```

Run in PHP 5.6.16

[image: php 5 refcount]

Run in PHP 7.0.2

[image: php 7 refcount]

I think the result (PHP 7) should be:

```
string(6) "foobar" refcount(4)
s: (refcount=3, is_ref=0)="foobar"
```

I wonder what makes the difference? Need some explanation. Thanks a lot.

------ update ------

Nikita Popov's - PHP 7 – What changed internally? (P41)

http://www.slideshare.net/nikita_ppv/php-7-what-changed-internally

[image: slideshare]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php

Comment: @devpro It's php 5.x

Comment: nothing changed in both.. conceptual

Comment: @devpro why refcount is 0?

Comment: @devpro it's 3 in php 5.x

Comment: ref count either 0 or 1, its part of reference set 0 1 indicate either part of or not... anyway i am not the downvoter.... and i suggest to downvoter plz recommend the improvements.

Comment: actually u can ask why refcount is 0 ... its valid question... bro..

Comment: https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html

Comment: @Steve http://www.slideshare.net/nikita_ppv/php-7-what-changed-internally

P41 says 3.

Comment: PHP7 seems to distinguish between value types that are refcounted and the ones that aren’t. It seems strings are refcounted sometimes. String literals (“interned strings”) aren’t (and probably don’t reside on the heap) which is why you get `0`. Also, these debug methods don’t seem to be particularly well updated for PHP 7 or they would output the info from the [`type_info` field in a zval](https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html#zval-memory-management).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In PHP 7 a zval can be reference counted or not. There is a flag in the zval structure which determined this.

There are some types which are never refcounted. These types are null, bool, int and double.

There are other types which are always refcounted. These are objects, resources and references.

And then there are types, which are *sometimes* refcounted. Those are strings and arrays.

For strings the not-refcounted variant is called an "interned string". If you're using an NTS (not thread-safe) PHP 7 build, which you typically are, all string literals in your code will be interned. These interned strings are deduplicated (i.e. there is only one interned string with a certain content) and are guaranteed to exist for the full duration of the request, so there is no need to use reference counting for them. If you use opcache, these strings will live in shared memory, in which case you *can't* use reference counting  for them (as our refcounting mechanism is non-atomic). Interned strings have a dummy refcount of 1, which is what you're seeing here.

For arrays the not-refcounted variant is called an "immutable array". If you use opcache, then constant array literals in your code will be converted into immutable arrays. Once again, these live in shared memory and as such must not use refcounting. Immutable arrays have a dummy refcount of 2, as it allows us to optimize certain separation paths.